# Google Drive SDK API: Instead of Permission.getName() to show name, is there way to display as permission in email

Tags: google-drive-api

If I do this (the following code), it shows name (Lanny Boy) instead of email (lannyboy@mydomain.com). I checked all the Permission available API extension, nothing can help to resolve permission in email address.

```
PermissionList permissions = service.permissions().list(file.getId()).execute();

for (Permission permission : permissions.getItems()) {
     System.out.println(permission.getName());
}
```

To insert permission, I use permission.setValue() to add as email address. But when I do as permission.getValue() to retrieve email information, all returns null @@" Why?

```
PermissionList permissions = service.permissions().list(file.getId()).execute();

for (Permission permission : permissions.getItems()) {
     System.out.println(permission.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think I can do is to use Google Apps Provisioning as

```
String fullName = userEntry.getName().getGivenName() + " " + userEntry.getName().getFamilyName();
```

to check against with permission.getName()